# Algorithms for rainfall + river creation in procedurally generated terrain

Tags: maps, procedural-generation, terrain, world-design

I've recently become fascinated by the things that can be done with procedurally terrain and have started experimenting with world building a bit. I'd like to be able to make worlds something like Dwarf fortress with biomes created from meshing together various maps.

So first step has been done. Using the diamond-square algorithm I've created some nice hieghtmaps. Next step is I would like to add some water features and have them somewhat realistically generated with rainfall. I've read about a few different approaches such as starting at the high points of the map, and "stepping" down to the lowest neighboring point, pooling/eroding as it works its way down to sea level.

Are there any documented algorithms with this or are they more off the cuff?

Would love any advice/thoughts.

Comment: I've implemented bits and pieces from the algorithm described in [this paper](http://web.mit.edu/cesium/Public/terrain.pdf).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Amit Patel, a user of this site, has created a [wonderful resource](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/) of information about random world generation that will certainly be of use to you.

Further there are some great questions/answers about procedural generation on this site.

[Road / river generation on 2d grid map](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31263/road-river-generation-on-2d-grid-map)

[Procedural world  generation oriented on gameplay features](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14004/procedural-world-generation-oriented-on-gameplay-features)

[How can I generate random lakes and rivers in my game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29044/how-can-i-generate-random-lakes-and-rivers-in-my-game)

[Random map generation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31241/random-map-generation?lq=1)

Answer (score 37):

Back when I experimented with this type of thing (late 1990s), I read some papers and books to learn about water flow, but I didn't keep a record of which ones I looked at. I ended up doing my own thing because I wanted to handle erosion. I wanted rivers to produce canyons and floodplains. I wanted dam reservoirs to fill up with sediment. I wanted rivers to produce effects like meandering and oxbow lakes. I wanted canals for irrigation and water diversion. I wanted floods to damage farms and houses in floodplains.

I kept some notes (links) in the Geography section of [this page](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/simblob/economy.html#geography). There's a Jos Stam paper that is a must-read. Unfortunately I never organized the notes. Also unfortunately, the game was for OS/2 so I can't easily give you a runnable executable to play with. And also unfortunately, my code is terrible, but if you want to take a look, see [water.cpp in the source code](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/simblob/simblob_source.zip) (zip).

Things I played with in my simulation (not all realistic):

- Areas near rivers have moist soil; areas far from rivers have dry soil. Moisture affected vegetation. Vegetation slows water flow.
- Rain creates water in all places, some of the time. It then flows downhill. Then it evaporates and is absorbed by the ground. The rain carves out river channels.
- Springs create water all the time, but only in a few locations. The springs keep the river channels filled. I didn't simulate rock layers or groundwater flow; I just placed springs randomly on mountains.
- Flowing water has momentum. If I remember right, this was important for making rivers meander.
- Fast moving water picks up sediment; slow moving water deposits sediment ahead of it. This carves out river valleys.
- During initial map creation I accelerated the water flow and erosion; during gameplay it ran at normal speed.

Overall, my experience was that all of this was quite *fun* to play with, but it took lots of heuristics and tweaking to make it work. I never got to a point where I could say that river creation felt natural and inevitable without tweaking. It was so much fun (both as a programmer and as a player) that I spent years on it, and never finished the rest of the game. :)

Comment: Simply speak his name and he shall arrive.

Comment: @Byte56 He's like the Candlejack of stackexcha....

Comment: You inspired me to write an imlementation based on your hexagon grid article and now you inspire me again!

Answer (score 1):

Most of the implementations I've seen have either been combining a "river map" (using a narrow band from Perlin noise or some similar approach) or the "raindrop" method you mention.

Here are a few jump-off points:

- the [Virtual Terrain Project's page on water](http://vterrain.org/Water/)
- [Shamus Young's exploration into river generation](http://www.shamusyoung.com/twentysidedtale/?p=12076)
- a collection of resources at [the Procedural Content Genereration Wiki](http://pcg.wikidot.com/pcg-algorithm%3afractal-river-basins)